# OpenIndiana poor write speed with 32Gb RAM and 64Gb ZIL

Tags: nfs, vmware-vsphere

I am getting poor write performance on a NFS share hosted with OpenIndiana 151a.
I have 2x 1 TB Mirror (Seagate constellation drives), 2 SSD drives, 1 read cache and 1 write cache. My thinking was, that by using a write cache I would gain SSD like performance even though I have a pretty slow hard disk. I am getting an avg of 40 MB/s. I should note that both my SSD drives are SATA3 capable of 500 MB/s. I feel cheated!
My setup is as follows:

- ESXi 5, NFS datastore, MTU set to 9000 on VMkernel and vSwitch
- VM1 OpenIndiana hosting the datastore, resides on direct attached storage.
- VM2 Windows XP with 2 10GB hard drive, 1 system drive, 2nd testing drive, using HD tune pro, resides on NFS datastore.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am busy running a spectrum of IOmeter tests, will post results when I am done.

I am not seeing the advertised SATA3 speeds here, would I just be better off using the SSD's as direct attached storage? In other words, is NFS the problem here?

Comment: Please provide more information on how you're testing the speed. Are you using two vSwitches?

Comment: Nope just 1 vSwitch with both the OpenIndiana (NAS) VM connected, and the Windows XP test VM connected, the VMkernel is also on the switch. The whole test vm as well as the 10Gb virtual disk pictured above is stored on the NFS share that is provided through OI.

Comment: You should separate the storage traffic onto another switch. One interface from the OpenIndiana box should be serving ESXi on a dedicated switch. See my answer below.

Comment: Please please please, update your question and title to use MB/GB where appropriate. These are **very** different than Mb/Gb by a factor of 8.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely on what and how you're testing. Is that 40Mb/sec read or write speed? Or combined? If your benchmarking software is all sequential reads or writes, chances are that you won't see a benefit from the SSD cache units.

Your virtual switch setup should look something like this. I'm using NexentaStor instead of OpenIndiana, but the same principles apply. The storage server should have a private switch with a VMkernel port. That's to provide NFS to the ESXi host. Then, you present a datastore to the ESXi system and place your VMs on it. You don't need a physical adapter, and using the VMXNET3 network adapter, things should show up as 10GbE.

[image]

Comment: I see the VMKernel port seems to be on another network, or is your subnet mask here 255.255.0.0?

Comment: I have two VMkernel ports in this example. Mask is /24. The vSwitch1 is for communication between ESXi and the Nexenta NFS datastore.

Comment: What would be the ip of the datastore (nexenta box) then in this example? Im talking about vSwitch1.

Comment: I would use 192.168.50.3. The Nexenta server has two interfaces. One for communication with ESXi, the other for management and ssh access (192.168.10.x).

Comment: I ask because I cannot connect to the datastore when I setup OI and the VMkernel on a seperate vswitch. I am using 10.0.1.0/24 subnet for this switch. I point to the OI box (10.0.1.1) when adding the datastore. My VMkernel's IP is set to 10.0.1.2, and none of the VMkernel port options are selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It keeps giving me the error "Unable to connect to NFS server". It's like it does not know which VMkernel to use.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ZIL isn't a "write cache", more a performant journal, thus you'd still be getting the raw disk's speed at best. Although 40MB/s is less than that and that's where "how did you do those tests" comes into play.

Correction: I was told I'm wrong and ZIL does double function as write cache, but not sure how/if this is all correct.

Comment: All (synchronous) writes are written to ARC (in mem), and if slog is configured then (synchronous) writes are written to it, and when successful: acknowledged back to client. Flushing is performed (about) once per 5 seconds iirc. In some sense this also reduce the random writes back to the disks, as the data to be flushed can be written in an as organized manner as possible (in terms of head movement). Needless to say; if no slog/zil, written to disks (or bbu), then acknowledged.

Comment: Btw, you are probably correct. For a continuous stream of written (synchronous) data, it will be limited to the write speed of the (given i/o pattern of the) disks. It's really more useful to achieve high random iops than to raw synchronous continuous writes.

Comment: thanks 3molo, this raises the level of detail to a useful amount of information!!

Comment: Very welcome! I say probably because I am still in my infancy regarding ZFS. If I am not correct, someone please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

vSphere mounts all NFS shares with sync, meaning all writes are done synchronous. If you instead mount the LUNs over iSCSI - all specifically synchronous writes will be synchronous - and the rest will be asynchronous.

To answer regarding the SSD as ZIL then; For a continuous stream of written (synchronous) data, it will be limited to the write speed of the (given i/o pattern of the) disks. ZIL is really more useful to achieve high random iops than to raw synchronous continuous writes.

In most cases, the amount of sequential data is not as important of a factor as how many truly random writes and reads you can handle - especially not in virtualized environments where you are likely to have many different "clients" hitting the storage. **Consider async writes if you need high throughput by using iSCSI instead of NFS.**